# General question: What to pass as pointer in C/C++?

Tags: c++, performance, pointers

Hey there,
I wonder if it's worth passing primitive single values like `int`, `float`, `double` or `char` by pointer? Probably it's not worth!? But if you would simply pass everything by pointer, is this making the program slower?
Should you always just pass arrays as pointer?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wonder if it's worth passing primitive single values like int, float, double or char by pointer?

What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to be able to write to the passed in value? Or do you just need to use it? If you want to write to it, the idiomatic way is to pass by **reference**. If you don't need to write to it, you're best avoiding any risk that you'll write to it accidentally and pass by value. Pass by value will make a copy of the variable for local use. (as an aside, if you don't want to make a copy AND want some level of safety, you can pass by [const reference](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html))

> But if you would simply pass everything by pointer, is this making the program slower?

Difficult to say. Depends on a lot of things. In both pass by value and pass by reference (or pointer) your making a new primitive type. In pass by value, you're making a copy. In pass by reference/pointer you're passing an address to the original. In the latter case, however, you're requiring an extra fetch of memory that may or may not be cached. Its very difficult to say 100% without measuring it.

That all being said, I doubt the difference is even noticeable. The compiler may be able to optimize out the copy in many pass-by-value cases, as indicated in this [article](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/). (thanks Space C0wb0y).

> Should you always just pass arrays as pointer?

From [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/).

> In C++ it is not possible to pass a complete block of memory by value as a parameter to a function, but we are allowed to pass its address.

To pass an array:

```
 int foo(int bar[], unsigned int length)
 {
       // do stuff with bar but don't go past length
 }
```

I'd recommended avoiding arrays and using std::vector which has more easily understood copy semantics.

Comment: Okay thanks. I know to pass pointers or reference (pointers when using plain C) when I want to modify the value, that's clear. But I wondered how to best do it when I just need a copy of the value and don't need to modify the original one: When to use pointers than? I thought: only when the data passed is big, e.g. arrays, because to copy them probably would cost more time to just copy the adress to it in memory...

Comment: [This article series](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) explains in very much detail that pass-by-value can significantly speed up your code. The reason is that **pass-by-value does not always result in a copy being made**, due to copy-elision and return-value-optimization.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Can you think of any circumstance where a copy would be elided and the compiler couldn't optimize away a reference or pointer equally well?  AFAICT, all three would be optimized when the call is inlined.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not worth passing primitive values by pointer if your concern is speed -- you then have the overhead of the "indirection" to access the value.

However, pointers often are the "width of the bus", meaning the processor can send the whole value at once, and not "shift" values to send-down-the-bus.  So, it is possible pointers are transferred on the bus faster than smaller types (like `char`).  That's why the old Cray computers used to make their `char` values 32 bits (the width of the bus at that time).

Answer (score 2):

Look in your favorite C++ textbook for a discussion of "output parameters".

---

Some advantages of using a pointer for output parameters instead of a reference are:

- No surprising behavior, no action at a distance, the semantics are clear at the call site as well as the caller.
- Compatibility with C (which your question title suggests is important)
- Usable by other languages, functions exported from a shared library or DLL should not use C++-only features such as references.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with large objects (such as classes or arrays) passing pointer is faster than copying the whole object onto the stack. This applies to OOP for example

Answer (score 1):

You should rarely have to pass anything by pointer. If you need to modify the value of the parameter, or want to prevent a copy, pass by reference, otherwise pass by value.

Note that preventing a copy can also be done by copy-elision, so you have to be very careful not to fall into the trap of premature optimization. This can actually make your code slower.

Answer (score 1):

There's is no real answer to your question except few rules that I tend to bare in mind:
char is 8 bytes and a pointer is 4 bytes so never pass a single char as a pointer.
after things like int and float are the same size as a pointer but a pointer has to be referenced so that technically takes more time

if we go to the pentium i386 assembler:

loading the value in a register of a parameter "a" in C which is an int:

```
movl 8(%ebp),%eax
```

the same thing but passed as a pointer:

```
movl 8(%ebp),%eax
movl (%eax),%eax
```

Having to dereference the pointer takes another memory operation so theorically (not sure it is in real life) passing pointers is longer...
After there's the memory issue. If you want to code effectively everything composed type (class,structure,arrays...) has to be passed by pointer.
Just imagine doing a recursive function with a type of 16bytes that is passed by copy for 1000 calls that makes 16000 bytes in the stack (you don't really want that do you ? :) )

So to make it short and clear: Look at the size of your type if it's bigger than a pointer pass it by pointer else pass it by copy...

Answer (score 1):

Pass primitive types by value and objects as `const` references. Avoid pointers as much as you can. Dereferencing pointers have some overhead and it clutters code. Compare the two versions of the `factorial` function below:

```
// which version of factorial is shorter and easy to use?

int factorial_1 (int* number)
{
  if ((*number) <= 1)
    return 1;
  int tmp = (*number) - 1;
  return (*number) * factorial_1 (&tmp);
}

// Usage:
int r = 10;
factorial_1 (&r); // => 3628800


int factorial_2 (int number)
{
  return (number <= 1) ? 1 : (number * factorial_2 (number - 1));
}

// Usage:
// No need for the temporary variable to hold the argument.
factorial_1 (10); // => 3628800
```

Debugging becomes hard, as you cannot say when and where the value of an object could change:

```
int a = 10;
// f cound modify a, you cannot guarantee g that a is still 10.
f (&a); 
g (&a);
```

Prefer the `vector` class over arrays. It can grow and shrink as needed and keeps track of its size. The way `vector` elements are accessed is compatible with arrays:

```
int add_all (const std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    size_t sz = vec.size ();
    int sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
        sum += vec[i]; 
}
```

Comment: Pointers have no more overhead than references.

Comment: Are references available in plain C or only in C++? I'm writing mex-files in Matlab and this is only plain C not C++... ;)

Comment: @Ben Voigt You are right. You need to take up that overhead only for large objects, not objects that are a few bytes in size (char, int etc).

Comment: @Col: Just added to my answer, compatibility with other languages is an important reason to use pointers.

Comment: @ColHeather I'm pretty sure that references only exists in C++ (not 100% sure though). @VijayMathew I don't agree with you and the Vector class vectors must be used in 90% of the cases However for an array that won't be resized using a standard array (int array[]) is much more efficient and less greedy in memory as you don't need all the resizing possibilities that the vector class gives. As usual there's no direct answer just think before coding!

Comment: @charly I said "prefer vector over arrays" not "avoid arrays".

Answer (score 0):

**NO**, the only time you'd pass a *non-const reference* is if the function requires an output parameter.

Comment: The only time I'd use a reference for an output parameter is when implementing user-defined operators.  What you are suggesting violates the principle of least surprise.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, On a side note on POLA, surely if the interface (function specification) states that it takes a non-const reference, the expectation is already set? So - why would it be a surprise?

Comment: With pointers, the mutability of the parameter is apparent at the call site, therefore it's less surprising.  If you assume full knowledge of the function specification for every call, why even bother with readable function names?